# Como exibir o resultado de uma busca no mysql onde retorna mais de 10mil resultado sem travar o navegador?

Tags: php, mysql, query, select

Atualmente to usando o table o jquery pra exibir os resultados, mas demora muito exibir todos os resultados e enquanto não termina a busca o navegador as vezes trava.
tem alguma forma melhor de mostrar os resultados mas sem travar o navegador?

onde ta $querypersonalizada seria um `"SELECT * FROM tb_clientes"` onde retornaria a uns 10mil resultados

```
            <!-- - Tabela usuario  começo  -->
        <div class="form" id="frmFiltro">

         <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="minhaTabela">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>id</th>
                  <th>nome</th>
                  <th>cpf</th>
                  <th>data nascimento</th>
                  <th>cidade</th>
                  <th>celular</th>
                  <th>telefone ok</th>
                  <th>tpcliente</th>
                  <th>stcliente</th>
                  <th>atendente</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>

<?php

$result = $conexao->query($querypersonalizada);
              $qtd_reg_filtro = mysqli_num_rows($result); //quantidade de registro

               echo $qtd_reg_filtro." Registro(s) encontrado(s)!"; //mostra a quantidade de registro
               if($result){
                 while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <?php echo '<td>'. $row['cli_id'].'</td>'; ?>
                      <?php echo '<td><a id="linkCliNome" href="viewcliente.php?id='.$row['cli_id'].'" target="_blank">'. $row['cli_nome'].'</a></td>'; ?>
                      <?php echo '<td>'. $row['cli_cpf'].'</td>'; ?>
                      <?php echo '<td>'. $row['cli_data_nascimento'].'</td>'; ?>
                      <?php echo '<td>'. $row['cli_cidade'].'</td>'; ?>
                      <?php echo '<td>'. $row['cli_celular'].'</td>'; ?>
                      <?php echo '<td>'. $row['cli_telefone_ok'].'</td>'; ?>
                      <?php echo '<td>'. $row['cli_tp_cliente'].'</td>'; ?>
                      <?php echo '<td>'. $row['cli_st_cliente'].'</td>'; ?>
                      <?php echo '<td>'. $row['cli_atendente'].'</td>'; ?>
                  </tr>


              <?php } 
              $result->free();
          } ?>

      </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#minhaTabela').DataTable({
          "language": {
             "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ registros por página",
             "zeroRecords": "Nada encontrado",
             "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
             "infoEmpty": "Nenhum registro disponível",
             "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)"
         }
     });
   });
</script>

</div>
<!--  Tabela usuario  FIM  -->
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código? Sem o código fica difícil ajudá-lo

Comment: vou colocar o codigo

Comment: Utilize Ajax do jQuery para realizar a chamada da função do php, desta forma a ui não ficará travada enquanto a consulta estiver sendo feito. Isso não vai garantir que o browser não fique lento

Comment: acho que entendi, vou tentar (Y)